# Ginibre inequality in Aizenman & Simon paper

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-statistics

In the paper linked below equation (4) is not well justified. After a lot of reasoning I still can't figure out why the need of taking the hamiltonian in the H' form and how should I use Ginibre inequality to show that "increasing $\lambda$ increases $2<\sigma_\alpha^{(1)}\sigma_\gamma^{(1)}>$".

You can here find the link to the article -> http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960180904934

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Also [on Simon's site](http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/129.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $\vec S_k=(\cos\theta_k,\sin\theta_k)$ the XY spin at $k$ and by 
$\langle\cdot\rangle'_{{\rm XY}}$ the expectation w.r.t. the 
Gibbs measure with Hamiltonian $H'$ (introduced in the paper).
Observe that
$$
\langle \vec S_i \cdot \vec S_j \rangle'_{\beta,{\rm XY}}
=
\langle \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j) \rangle'_{{\rm XY}}.
$$
Now,
\begin{multline*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda} \langle \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j) 
\rangle'_{{\rm XY}}
=\\
\sum_{k} \bigl\{ \underbrace{\langle \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j) 
\cos(4\theta_k) \rangle'_{{\rm XY}}
-
\langle \cos(\theta_i-\theta_j)\rangle'_{{\rm XY}}
\langle \cos(4\theta_k) \rangle'_{{\rm XY}} }_{\geq 0}
\bigr\}
\geq 0,
\end{multline*}
which proves the desired monotonicity. The inequality above is a direct 
application of the following particular case of Ginibre's inequality:
$$
\bigl\langle \cos(\sum_k m_k\theta_k) \cos(\sum_k m'_k \theta_k) \bigr\rangle 
\geq
\bigl\langle \cos(\sum_k m_k\theta_k) \bigr\rangle \langle\cos(\sum_k m'_k 
\theta_k) \bigr\rangle,
$$
valid for arbitrary collections $(m_k)_{k},(m'_k)_k$ of integers.
The comparison with the 4-state Potts 
model then follows, since the latter is recovered when $\lambda\to+\infty$, since the only values of $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ such that $\cos(4\theta)=1$ are $0,\pi/2,\pi,3\pi/2$, and these 4 values can be identified with the 4 states of this Potts model.
That is, denoting by $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\rm XY}$ the expectation under the original XY Gibbs measure (with Hamiltonian $H$) and by $\langle\cdot\rangle_{\rm Potts}$ the expectation under the 4-state Potts model, the monotonicity implies that
$$
\langle\vec S_i\cdot \vec S_j\rangle_{\rm XY} = 
\langle\vec S_i\cdot \vec S_j\rangle'_{\rm XY,\lambda=0}
\leq
\langle\vec S_i\cdot \vec S_j\rangle'_{\rm XY,\lambda=+\infty}
= 
\langle\vec S_i\cdot \vec S_j\rangle_{\rm Potts}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Might you expand on why the functions $\cos(\sum_k m_k\theta_k)$ satisfy the Ginibre's inequality's conditions?

Comment: This is not trivial, and is explained in Example 4 in Section 2 of Ginibre's paper.

Comment: BTW, if you are only interested in the comparison between XY and Ising, then you might be interested in the alternative approach described in Theorem 9.16 in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/index.html). This approach is elementary, it bypasses the use of Ginibre's inequality and applies to general $O(N)$ models. (It does use Griffiths' inequality for the Ising model however, but the latter is elementary and also explained and proved in the book.)